# Is it possible to receive eCall by Asterisk (PSAP)?

Tags: asterisk, modem, dtmf, asteriskami

I found an interesting documeent about realisation of eCall (Emergency Call) in EU: http://www.heero-pilot.eu/ressource/static/files/heero_wp3_d3-3_final-operational-results_v2.3_final.pdf

Germany somehow did it on Asterisk. Whatever, I don't understand how they process MSD (minimal set of data) using Asterisk. In the call session for the first step caller sends DTMF signals to send MSD packet. As I understood, Asterisk must redirect this call to In-band modem on COM port or to another machine with such modem. After PSAP successfully received MSD for the second step caller switches to voice channel that must be redirected to some sip-client of PSAP operator. How they do it? Is there a way to receive DTMF signals w/o modem by using internal capabilities of Asterisk? How the same call to redirect to another SIP on the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are referring to emergency services, rendered by emergency dialers - eg. for senior citizens. These are fairly common where I live, and I've created in the past a solution to handle the calls from these, based on Asterisk. The solution involved a way to intercept the various DTMF signals that the device generates, then making Asterisk do stuff with it. Back then, I used Asterisk 1.6 and it is pain staking, because I had to do everything from within a MeetMe bridge, and interact with Manager alot. Today, doing the same with Asterisk 12/13 and ARI is a breeze. Just remember one thing, most of these dialers will utilize the A,B,C,D DTMF signals, which are somewhat unknown to most people - they exist and Asterisk is very much capable of handling those.

The only snag is - make sure you are connected via a PRI, as most SIP carriers aren't aware of these signals, and their SIP trunks won't support this type of signalling.

Comment: NirS, have you some sources from that project and configuration files for example? I could barely understand the realization of such PSAP.

Comment: Wow, sorry to say, that project was done over 6 years ago - I no longer have access to that code. The particular server had been put to its resting place about 3 years ago :-(

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk can send dtmf(natively,via command SendDTMF in dialplan or D option in Dial command) or any other sound(custom c/c++ app needed)

No, you not need special modem.

However there are no realisation acordinly to that document, you need do that yourself or hire someone